# The wrong date (LocalDate) saved in database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

I have the following problems:

- I send date as a string from angular - pattern "yy-mm-dd"
- I convert this String to LocalDate in Java.

Connection to DB:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/families?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Date is converted correctly - I checked this during debugging. But date is incorrect in the database, for example: I send `2018-12-02` but in db `2018-12-01` is saved.

Conversion from dto to entity

```
@Override
public Father convertToEntity(FatherDto fromDto) {
    LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.parse(fromDto.getBirthDate(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        return new Father(fromDto.getId(), birthDate, fromDto.getFirstName(), fromDto.getLastName(), fromDto.getPesel(), fromDto.getSecondName());          
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface FatherRepository extends JpaRepository<Father, Integer> {  
}
```

Method used to save in db

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addFatherToFamily(int familyId, FatherDto fatherDto) {
    Family family = familyRepository.findById(familyId).get();
    Father father = fatherConverter.convertToEntity(fatherDto);
    father.setFamily(family);
    fatherRepository.save(father);
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `"yy-mm-dd"` with `"yy-MM-dd"` .

Comment: How are you storing the date? What is the query?

Comment: Please add all the relevant application/db code for saving the date

Comment: I believe i have to use "yy-mm-dd" in case of using LocalDate. 
I save the data just by using save() method by JPA repository.

Comment: This is more than likely a time-zone related problem Java LocalDate will, by default assume your computers timezone. If that is not the same as your mysql database (which appears to be UTC), then if you're not careful, you could wind up with a time-shift problem. LocalDate is a date, not a time, if you convert it to a time, it will be converted as a 'start-of-day' time. Start of day in UTC is, for example, 8 hours ahead of PST. So, you could easily wind up with a stored date which is a day ahead of the intended value.

Comment: @TomDrake so should I just change "UTC" in application.properties for for example UTC+8 or something like that?

Comment: what the code for fromDto.getBirthDate()??

Comment: Or you could just use a ZonedDate with UTC instead.

Comment: It is just basic gettter

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your database column? I suspect it is not a date-only type. Show the code that creates that column.